# Is this TortoiseSVN error also in your installation

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I've installed TortoiseSVN in `C > Program Files > TortoiseSVN`. I wanted to test it with command prompt, so I opened `cmd` and `cd` to the bin folder inside the TortoisSVN installation folder.

I tried `svn help` in the command prompt and it worked fine. 
Then I tried `svn status` and it gave me this error.

```
svn: warning: W155007: 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin' is not a working copy
```

Can someone try those 2 commands and tell me if they get similar results?

Comment: Might I suggest you look at the Subversion docs (http://svnbook.red-bean.com), so you'll understand what the command line tools do and how (and when) to use them? It's much safer that way. :)

Comment: Not to say one is better than the other, but Git's error message is much better IMO: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error:

```
svn: warning: W155007: 'C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin' is not a working copy
```

Says that the directory `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin` is not a working copy of a SVN repository. A working copy contains a hidden `.svn/` folder with metadata, which is read by `svn`. The message is absolutely correct and isn't an error but a warning.

This happens because `svn help` doesn't require a working copy of a SVN repository to run properly. It just shows you the help text.

`svn status`, on the other hand, needs a Subversion repository.

Comment: To be clear: svn status doesn't need a repository but a "working copy".

Answer (score 3):

Of course everyone will get the same error. `svn status` is used to know the status of a wroking copy. If you're not inside a working copy, you'll get this error.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the path `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin` doesn't have the source code you're working on.  You need to call `svn status` from within a local working copy, not from the folder where the `svn.exe` executable is located.  Otherwise it doesn't know what working copy you're talking about.

So if your local code is in something like `C:\Data\Code\My Project\` then you'd need to `cd` to that folder and run the command from there.

Answer (score 1):

you can only run svn status on checkout code